# Control textbox with JavaScript by adding a string to dynamic id

Tags: javascript, textbox

I don't know why I am struggling with this. Should I be taking a different approach?
I have a form being generated in vb based off a database and then I am trying simply to make a text-box be disabled unless you check a checkbox.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mikesearcy/ve9Gz/) is what I have so far. It needs to be dynamic (what I have commented out).

I can't seem to get it to work. The difficult part is referencing

```
document.form1.el.id.toString() + "_other".disabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, this should work for you:

```
function enable_text(el) {
    var textbox_name = el.id.toString() + "_other";
    document.getElementById(textbox_name).disabled = 
       (el.checked) ? "" : "disabled"; 
}​
```

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ve9Gz/3/

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` is a binary property, not an attrbute.

You must use `disabled='disabled'` or remove the attribute to enable the element. It is not a true/false value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

http://jsfiddle.net/C2WaU/1/

Comment: Wow, people in here are fast, if you feel the question has been answered by others, I can remove my answer